# Some USBs do not show up in Computer under Windows 7 but still makes beboop sound?

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a Windows 7 machine that will not display some USBs under Computer, though some other ones do appear. When I plug any USB in I get the "beboop" sound saying something was plugged in, and sometimes I even get the "Installing device driver" popup, but I cannot see them still.

Any ideas?

EDIT: After leaving the USB in for sometime and opening Disk Management seems to show some of the USBs, but others still have the same issue.

Comment: If they are storage devices, you might be having a drive letter conflict. You might try, for the ones that show up, changing the drive letter to something far down the alphabet, but one you are less likely to have used before. The others with the conflict may then start to show up.

Comment: What do you mean by "under Computer"? Do you mean in the list of mounted filesystems when you click on "My Computer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "beboop" and "boobeep" are sounds for hardware attachment/detachment only. They do not mean that the device actually responded to enumeration attempt.

There could be several places where the enumeration can fail: device premature disconnect (due to signal integrity problem cross the cable or internal xHCI marginality), failure to complete FS/HS handshake (either on device or host side), power-on glitches on D- leading to false identification of device speed, etc.  A good way is to have the USBView.exe utility http://www.uwe-sieber.de/ (an improved version of Microsoft utility found in DDK), and see to what extent the system got all necessary descriptors.

The next problem with enumeration is VID/PID mismatch with installed drivers, or some descriptors reporting confusing information. That's where you get messages about failures to install drivers etc.

Sometimes the OS develops some sort of mis-syncronization between different layers of USB stack, so the host controller reset/re-initialization (or OS reboot) is required.